# Estimating parameters for a custom AR process

Tags: equation-solving, functions

I want to define a custom AR 2 process of the form:

$ X_t=\beta_1 X_{t-1}+\beta_2 X_{t-2}+\beta_3 y+\beta_4 z+ \epsilon$

where y and z are some "outside" variables like in a normal regression. And then estimate the parameters. However in Mathematica 12.1 I can only use preset AR processes as far as I know. Any help appreciated.